# Got Blank result when Adding Image to Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm new to Windows Phone Dev., I intend to do:

1. Set the canvas background with Image A;
2. Add another Image B on top of Image A.

**What I have achieved**:

By using `ImageBrush`, I'm able to set the canvas background image, but I got a problem when trying to use `Canvas.Children.Add(imageB)` to put imageB on top of Image A. When running the app, it only show me the imageA with no imageB on top.

There's no Null Reference Exception and I am sure that both Image A and B are loaded.

**My question** is: How to set canvas to display ImageB and keep imageB responsive to Manipulation event so I can touch and move it later?

Here's my related code:

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
Image imageB = new Image();
imageB.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/imageB.png", UriKind.Relative));

//...here I set the ImageBrush as imageA
canvas.Background = brush; // Can display imageA 

canvas.Children.Add(imageB);
imageB.ManipulationDelta += ImageB_ManipulationDelta;
imageB.ManipulationCompleted += ImageB_ManipulationCompleted;
```

The reason why I insist to put image B on top of Image A is I am planning to set EventHandler on Image B so that I can use Image B to repond to `ManipulationDelta` event.

I did some research on that:

[Windowsphone geek: Working with Images](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action)

[Windows Phone 7 dragging and flicking UI](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2010/12/19/windows-phone-7--dragging-and-flicking-ui-controls.aspx)

But no luck.

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just found where the problem is:

I didn't set the `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop`, I should add two lines before using `canvas.Children.Add()` like:

```
...
Canvas.SetLeft(imageB, point.X);
Canvas.SetTop(imageB, point.Y);
canvas.Children.Add(imageB);
...
```

and viola, Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you create an `Image` called `imageB` but you never set it. The line

```
Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/imageB.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

seems strange, shouln't it be

```
imageB.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/imageB.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Sorry its my typo. I've corrected my question, please refer to the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. after lots of search finally I've found the solution.
this code will work as you expect:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/imageB.png", UriKind.Relative));
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
Image imageB = new Image();
imageB.Source = img;
img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
    canvas.Children.Add(imageB);
};
```